# UILabel Text is not updating on UIButton clicked in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have wried issue. I have one button and one label.

```
@IBOutlet weak var addProductDetails: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var countProductDetails: UILabel!
```

I am able to click on that button and after that i am trying to update value of UILabel. But value is not updating.

```
  @IBAction func plusIconClicked1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var q = Int(self.countProductDetails.text!)!
    q = q + 1;
    if(q >= 0) {
        if(q>10) {
            AFWrapper.showError("", msg: "Sorry, You can't add more of these items")
        } else {
            print("plusIconClicked1")
            print("Value of Q is : \(q)")
             print("countProductDetails 1 ", countProductDetails)

            self.countProductDetails.text = "\(q)"
             print("countProductDetails 2 ", countProductDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

First Time Clicked on button and log is :

```
plusIconClicked1
Value of Q is : 1
countProductDetails 1  some(<UILabel: 0x7f862083bac0; frame = (238.5 90; 30.5 28); text = '0'; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f861e688930>>)
countProductDetails 2  some(<UILabel: 0x7f862083bac0; frame = (238.5 90; 30.5 28); text = '1'; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f861e688930>>)
```

Second Time clicked on button and log is:

```
plusIconClicked1
Value of Q is : 2
countProductDetails 1  some(<UILabel: 0x7f862083bac0; frame = (238.5 90; 30.5 28); text = '1'; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f861e688930>>)
countProductDetails 2  some(<UILabel: 0x7f862083bac0; frame = (238.5 90; 30.5 28); text = '2'; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f861e688930>>)
```

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint at `self.countProductDetails.text = String(q)` to verify that the code is being called?

Comment: First, add break point into `plusIconClicked1`, is it reachable? If yes, try to trace what's the reason of the issue...

Comment: @AhmadF yes it is reachable.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yes code is being called.

Comment: What's the value of `String(q)`?

Comment: @AhmadF First clicked on button and got value of String(q) = 1

Comment: And you only got one label in your view (and not - by coincidence - created two of them, one hiding the other)? And the size of the label is big enough to display the text (check by giving it an inital value of "1" in the storyboard)

Comment: Check if it is running on the main thread. If not try this - 

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.countProductDetails.text = String(q)
}`

Comment: @AndreasOetjen First time when i clicked it is not updating. But again when i am clicking it is updating to label. I got same issue in TableView where i reload the cell using **self.productTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: indexNo), with: .automatic)
 ** It works when cell refresh using animation **with: .automatic**

Comment: If this happening inside a `UITableViewCell`, then you need to call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` from the viewController which as the `tableView`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri tableviewcell issue has fixed. I just reloadSections with .automatic animation. But this is another issue which is on ViewController not Tableview

Comment: Hard to tell. It looks fine. Just add some `print()` statements to check which code is executed the first (and second) time you click, print out the variables etc.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I just edit the code with Logs.Kindly have a look. Internally value has been assigned to Label but not displaying. I think something needed invalidated or refresh??

Comment: No, you typically do not need a refresh or something. Maybe it is helpful if you create a small Xcode project that just shows your problem, upload it to some server and give us the link to it to check what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

just change from String(q) to

```
"\(q)"
```

Check q has a value in it.

Comment: Using the String initializer or the string interpolation should not make a difference at all

Comment: are you getting "plusIconClicked1" on the debugger  . and also check self.countProductDetails is not nil

Comment: @ scube Sys : can you please add the debugger output in here after adding q in the   print("plusIconClicked1") statement   like this  <br> print("Value of Q is : \(q)")

Comment: can you check the label is connected to the Xib or storyboard whatever you are using

Comment: Yes it is connected.

Answer (score 0):

By Looking to to your code **self.countProductDetails.text** is only change when **(q >= 0)&& (q <= 10).**

you can print value of q before

`if(q >= 0) {`

like this

`print("Value of Q is : \(q)")`

and check what will be the value of **q**

I think there is no issue in syntax. Please mention what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just clicked on button and following is log **plusIconClicked1
Value of Q is : 1** there is not issue with that. probably i need to refresh the view after updating.

Comment: then I think there is some problem with IBOutlet reference of label. Try to delete and reconnect self.countProductDetails outlet.